# Can I get the id of the javafxml object in an Action Event method, when it gets activated?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am trying to code a small rpg and I decided to put the basics into an fxml document (MenuBar with their items).
So now I am planning to open a new window when you click on the Menu Items (Character, Inventory & Equipment), so I can display the things there is an extra window. So it makes sense I want to set the title of each menu equivalent to the Text displayed on the MenuItem. Of course, I could just make an extra method for every menu item, but I am searching for a possibility, where I can get the id of the Menu Item, that fired the event, so I can use their getText method to get the tag.
Can somebody help me?

I tried to access the object with "this" and also thought about using an enum to connect the IDs to Objects of the enum MenuName, so I just have to put a switch in my method, thus creating the menu, but that also didn´t work out, cause there I cannot check which of the ids got fired. So for that part of my program, it doesn´t help.

Here´s the code in my controller class

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private void menuIsClickedDefault(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
          Stage secondStage = new Stage();
          Parent a = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("menus.fxml"));
          secondStage.setTitle(HERES_MY_PROBLEM);
          secondStage.setScene(new Scene(a, 646, 400));
          secondStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
          secondStage.show();
    }
}
```

and these are my fxml objects:

```
<MenuItem fx:id="stats" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Statistics" />
<MenuItem fx:id="inv" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Inventory" />
<MenuItem fx:id="equip" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Equipment" />
```

I didnt integrate the method in the objects yet, cause it doesn´t make sense without solving the problem and I know that the rest of the code is working due to a similar method for the settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `event.getSource()` to retrieve the node that triggered the event. You'll need to cast the returned object to the proper type, though.

```
private void menuIsClickedDefault(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
      Stage secondStage = new Stage();
      Parent a = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("menus.fxml"));

      // Get the source of this event and cast it to a MenuItem; then you can
      // retrieve its text property
      secondStage.setTitle(((MenuItem) event.getSource()).getText());

      secondStage.setScene(new Scene(a, 646, 400));
      secondStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
      secondStage.show();
}
```